# ¿No se muestra el encabezado de un PDF?

Tags: php, php7, fpdf

me encuentro en la necesidad de buscar nuevamente su ayuda. estoy intentando realizar un reporte en PDF. Al momento de cambiar el tamaño de mi hoja, no se visualiza, ya moví los parámetros y aun si no me permite visualizar la cabecera.

Le comparto el código y una imagen, estoy utilizando la orientación A4. Estoy utilizando la librería FPDF
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <?php
        require('../fpdf/fpdf.php');

        class PDF extends FPDF
        {
        // Cabecera de página
        function Header()
        {
            
            // Logo
            $this->Image('../img/ENCAB_PAG.jpg',10,8,33);
            // Arial bold 15
            $this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
            // Movernos a la derecha
            $this->Cell(80);
            // Título
            $this->Cell(30,10,utf8_decode('Lista de Reportes'),0,0,'C');
            // Salto de línea
            $this->Ln(20);
           


            $this->Cell(30,10,'Nombres',0, 0, 'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(75,10,'Direccion',0, 0,'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(10,10,'Telefono',0, 0, 'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(50,10,'No contrato', 0, 0,'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(30,10,'Descripcion', 0, 0,'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(30,10,'Fecha', 0, 0,'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(30,10,'Cuadrilla', 0, 0,'C', 0);
            $this->Cell(30,10,'Estados', 0, 1,'C', 0);
        }

        // Pie de página
        function Footer()
        {
            // Posición: a 1,5 cm del final
            $this->SetY(-15);
            // Arial italic 8
            $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
            // Número de página
            $this->Cell(0,10,utf8_decode('Page ').$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');

        }
        }
```

Comment: Y cómo o dónde usas esas funciones?

Comment: Cuando creo mi PDF al cambiar la orientación se pierde la cabecera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación de la librería **FPDF**, debes instanciar la clase en dónde sobreescribes los métodos Header y Footer. En este caso de acuerdo a las imágenes debes instanciar la clase **PDF**.

[Acá la sección en la documentación que describe el problema](http://www.fpdf.org/es/FAQ.php#q6)